# Payu android sdk integration - Default activity not found

Tags: android, build.gradle, payu

I am trying to using Payu gateway integration.So i added dependency **implementation 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.6.0'** .After sync  **Default activity not found ** coming.
Dont understand error. if i remove dependency ,its working fine.

Build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.6.0'
```

Manifest FIle :

```
  <activity
        android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add   tools:replace="android:allowBackup,android:usesCleartextTraffic" in the App Manifest file and
Invalidate and Restart the project once.